# $log_ab*log_ac$

Tags: logarithms

I was trying to make the thing tighter, but I don’t know how to expand $log_ab*log_ac$. What should I do? Specific problem: ${ln(3)}^2$

Comment: There is no simple formula for a product of logarithms.  There is a simple formula for sum of logarithms $\log_a(x)+\log_a(y) = \log_a(xy)$; there is a simple formula for the product of exponentials $a^x a^y = a^{x+y}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simplify further: using the change of base rule, you have:

$$\frac{\log b}{\log a} \cdot \frac{\log c}{\log a}$$
$$= \frac{\log b \log c}{\log^2 a}$$